# Do replication slots of Postgres get duplicated in cross region replication?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, logical-replication

I have a `PostgreSQL` DB on `Amazon RDS`. I need a replication available on a different AWS Region for having high availability. I read the Posgres Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html#USER_ReadRepl.XRgn). However, I'm not sure if the `replication slots` are also replicated (along with the `lsn's`).

Can someone throw some light on this? Also, if the replication slots are not duplicated on the RDS replica (in the different region), how do I manage a region failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, replication slots are not replicated.  You can, however, create replication slots on standby servers, if you want to use cascading replication.

There is no need to replicate a replication slot.

Comment: So suppose the entire region goes down, and I want to resume reading from the last read point. How do I handle that without duplicating replication slots on a different AWS region?

Comment: Why would you need to duplicate replication slots for failover?

Comment: I'm reading from a replication slot, and once the region goes down, I'd like to resume from where I had last read, rather than reading the entire stuff again.

Comment: You are not reading from replication slots, but from a server. The standby knows the location where to resume replication, so you don't have to worry about that. Replication slots just keep primaries from discarding WAL information that a standby might still need. If you fail over to another server, you should create a replication slot there as part of the failover process.